# What if data folder already exists on root C

Tags: mongodb

When installing MongoDB I have a server that already has a folder named data. IS the  an alternate naming convention I can use for MongoDB?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before starting the mongod server, you can define the path of where is your "data" folder located. So, you can create another one either in C: or anywhere else.

Look at the documentation here https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/ under the section **Start MongoDB Community Edition from the Command Interpreter**

You can also set up a configuration file so you don't have to manually tell mongod where is the path every time its started. This info is also in the link, under **Start MongoDB Community Edition as a Windows Service**

Comment: Thank you, Roger! Appreciate the time you took to respond. This is perfect!

Comment: @imagnsupport I'm glad to help! If this answer actually solves your problem please go ahead and select it as the accepted one